# Intuitive visualization that the rotational symmetry group of $S^3$ as $SO(4)=(S^3\times S^3)/\mathbf{Z}/2$

Tags: algebraic-topology, lie-groups, lie-algebras, projective-geometry, group-isomorphism

How do we gain an intuitive visualization that the rotational symmetry group of $S^3$ as $$SO(4)=(S^3\times S^3)/\mathbf{Z}/2?$$

techinically I know that there are following isomorphism and diffeomrphisms of these differentiable manifolds:

$$Spin(4)=SU(2) \times SU(2)=(S^3\times S^3).$$
$$SO(4)=Spin(4)/\mathbf{Z}/2=(SU(2) \times SU(2))/\mathbf{Z}/2=(S^3\times S^3)/\mathbf{Z}/2.$$
$$PSO(4)=Spin(4)/(\mathbf{Z}/2)^2=(SU(2) \times SU(2))/(\mathbf{Z}/2)^2=(SO(3)\times SO(3)).$$

> **How do we show the above can all be intuitive visualized?**

Comment: This question is about 6-dimensional groups acting on 4-dimensional spaces; I don't think the can be "visualized" in any reasonable (much less intuitive) way. That said, these isomorphisms can be described simply enough using quaternions.

Comment: thanks, but (4)=(2)×(2)=(3×3). is 6 dimensional, and it is easy to visualize because you can just product two 3-spheres. I mean visualized in the sense we can break down to some easier visualizable pieces such as what I said here :)

Answer (score 2):

This isomorphism is known as the isoclinic decomposition; the [wikipedia page on $SO(4)$](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rotations_in_4-dimensional_Euclidean_space) describes it in more detail. While it may or may not count as an "intuitive visualization", it can be described quite compactly using quaternions:

We can identify $\mathbb{R}^4$ with the space of quaternions $\mathbb{H}$, and $S^3$ with the group of unit quaternions. $S^3$ acts on $\mathbb{H}$ by left multiplication and right multiplication, giving two actions $R,L$. Since these actions are norm preserving and $S^3$ is connected, both map into $SO(4)$. Further, since the actions commute, they give rise to an action $\rho:S^3\times S^3\to SO(4)$ defined by $\rho_{(a,b)}q=L_aR_bq=aqb^{-1}$. One can show that $\rho$ is surjective and $\ker(\rho)=\{(1,1),(-1,-1)\}$.